# text doesn't display correctly with icon

Tags: react-native

I'm using Native-base components to create a card. 
But, i find a problem in displaying  icons with text. I want to display it like this :

[image]

But i get this result :

[image]

This is my code :

```
 <Card style= {{  flex: 1  ,   width :  width-30 , marginTop :10}}>  
      <CardItem cardBody>
          <Image source= { require('./images/post-media/1.png') } style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}}>
      </Image>
       </CardItem>
      <CardItem style = {{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
       <Body>
         <Text style= {styles.txt}>
         this is my text blabla blabla blabla  
         </Text>
         <View style={{  borderBottomWidth: 1,  borderBottomColor: '#839fcc',  width: width-70 }} /> 
       </Body>
     </CardItem>
        <CardItem >
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
            <Icon  name="time" style={styles.icon} />
            <Text>2017.07.05 </Text>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Button transparent > 
            <Icon  name="heart"   style={styles.icon} />
            <Text >325</Text>
            </Button>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Icon  name="chatbubbles"   style={styles.activeIcon}  />
            <Text>325</Text>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
```

For the style :

```
    icon: {
     color: '#839fcc' 
     },
    activeIcon:{
   color:'#0d5be9'
    }
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear,but from the screen shot i see that breakage is the problem.

Import these things from the below library(this answer works only if you use this library)

```
  import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
```

In you code use the Row tag and give proper flux to place the icon and  text in proper manner.

```
       <CardItem >
           <Left>
            <Row>
             <Button transparent>
           <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <View style={{flex: 2}}>
                <Icon  name="time" style={styles.icon} />
               </View>
            <View style={{flex: 2}}>
               <Text>2017.07.05 </Text>
            </View>
          </View> 
            </Button>
            </Row>
          </Left>
        </CardItem>
```

Above i have only edited the left tag , use flux or else it will break in different screen sizes.By properly altering the flux values you can arrange their position in suitable manner.

Comment: my problem is the space between icon and text.  Ihave to delete it

Comment: give me the full code...i think you mean the blah blah text but that is not present in your code.

Comment: just place everything in single card-item tag,why do you use three,place the image first,then the text and view and then use row tag to arrange the icon+text as i mentioned above in my anwser